# Method in protocol not implemented in iOS

Tags: ios5, protocols

I do not understand because the error appears "Method in protocol not implemented"

myProtocol.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol myProtocol <NSObject>

-(UIImage *)transferImage;

@end
```

ViewController.h

```
#import "SecondClass.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<myProtocol, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

{
UIView *view;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *imageView;

- (IBAction)sendImage:(id)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "myProtocol.h"
@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"VoodooVibe@2x.png"]];

[view addSubview:_imageView];

NSLog(@"I am in VC.m");
}

-(UIImage *)transferImage{
NSLog(@"I am in transferImage");
return _imageView.image;}
- (IBAction)sendImage:(id)sender {
SecondViewController *secClass = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
```

secClass.delegate=self;[secClass callTransfer];NSLog(@"I am in sender");[self.navigationController pushViewController:secClass animated:YES];}

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

SecondViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "myProtocol.h"

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController :               UIViewController<myProtocol,UINavigationControllerDelegate> {

UIView *secondView;

IBOutlet UIImageView *myImage;

id <myProtocol> myDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic,strong) UIImageView *myImage;

@property(nonatomic,weak) id delegate;

-(void)callTransfer;

@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

#import "ViewController.h"

#import "myProtocol.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize delegate,myImage;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

[secondView addSubview:myImage];
}
-(void)callTransfer

{
myImage.image=[delegate performSelector:@selector(transferImage)];

myImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"VoodooVibe@2x.png"];

NSLog(@"%@",myImage.image);

NSLog(@"I am in call transfer");

}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: the next time, you should just insert the code which really is important for this question. In this case it you just need your `delegate` file and maybe the file the warning appeared. Maybe you can edit your post to shorten it a little bit.

Comment: Could you please look if one of the posts answers your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is as simple as you have declared a method in your protocol implementation but have not implemented the same. In your Second VC you have not implemented the method "tranfer image" . So the compiler is generating a warning

Comment: I have one more question: Without implementing the required method also app is working and gives a warning, but it should give an error right?

Answer (score 5):

You call the `delegate` method inside the `SecondViewController` but you didn't insert it. If you get a warning like `... not implemented` it just says, you forgot to include a method. 
You could insert the method like this

```
-(UIImage *)transferImage{
    //do something here if delegate has been called
}
```

or you just add a parameter above the method inside your `delegate` block:

```
@optional
```

if you don't specify it, all methods will be set to `@required` initial.